# wrong result from custom function depending on return()

Tags: r

It happens that there are three very different behaviours while calculating a value as a straight calculus or putting it in a function, with or without a `NA`.

Having two vectors:

```
vec=c(1,2,3,4,5,62,2,2,7,7,9,9,9,4,2,3,1)
vec2=c(1,2,3,4,5,62,2,2,7,7,9,9,9,4,2,3,1,NA)
```

I do the same calculation

```
(mean(vec, na.rm = TRUE) - min(vec, na.rm = TRUE))/(max(vec, na.rm = TRUE) - min(vec, na.rm = TRUE))


(mean(vec2, na.rm = TRUE) - min(vec2, na.rm = TRUE))/(max(vec2, na.rm = TRUE) - min(vec2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

...and I get the same result (0.11), while applying it through a function

```
no_fun = function(x){(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))/(max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))}


no_fun(vec)
> 8
    
no_fun(vec2)
> 9
```

I get two different results.
The incredible part -if this was not enough- is that adding `return()` to the function

```
no_fun= function(x){return((mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))/(max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)))}
```

I get the correct value (0.11).

Why does this happen?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Your function works correct on my machine.

Comment: I concurr with @TarJae ... all functions work correctly on my machine aswell

Comment: You may have to specify the R version etc.  as others can't reproduce it.  I tried on `R 4.1.2` on R console and get both 0.11 `> no_fun(vec)#
[1] 0.1108968` without any `return`

Comment: `R 4.1.2` too on W10...btw, after full restart, this morning works fine: I don't know what to say. Might that happen as a conflict between packages?